# Hide and show a div based on mobile browser and desktop browser

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

I divided my content in to two div's left one is for qty,price,item name and right div is for product names.

now i want display left div in mobile browsers by hiding product names div and in desktop browsers i want to show both.

[image: screen]

Comment: tried using media queries? are u using bootstrap for this?

Comment: If you are using Bootstrap, it has built in classes to show/hide elements based on Desktop, Mobile etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Bootstrap, you can check it's responsive classes to show/hide different elements on Mobile/Desktop, here:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

If you are not using bootstrap or any other library that has such help classes built-in, then you need to write your own media query, something like:

CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 767px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .price, .left-div { display: none; }   
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-div"> TEXT TEXT</div>   
  <div class="price"> $49</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a media query

```
@media (max-width:767px){
    .whatever{display:none;}
}
```